# Scala Swing component sizing

Tags: swing, scala, components

Scala is an awesome language, but unfortunately the library documentation is lacking. How do I change the initial size of a component? I have nothing on it (intentionally), but would like it to be a certain size anyway. I currently have

```
...
contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
    contents += new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
        contents += buttons(0)
        contents += buttons(1)
        contents += buttons(2)
    }
    contents += new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
        contents += buttons(3)
        contents += buttons(4)
        contents += buttons(5)
    }
    contents += new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
        contents += buttons(6)
        contents += buttons(7)
        contents += buttons(8)
    }
    border = Swing.EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
}
...
```

`buttons` is an array of `scala.swing.Button`s. Unfortunately they all show up very small when the application is run. I'd like them to be about 60x60 pixels each, though any reasonably large square would suffice.

Comment: This is more of a swing question, but here is some guidance: http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/17138-jbutton-size.html

Comment: Well, there's a big difference between regular Swing and Scala's scala.swing wrapper libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting a preferred size on the buttons?

```
buttons foreach { _.preferredSize = new Dimension(60, 60) }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. The buttons stay tiny.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the layout.  You could try setting the preferredSize when you construct each button (e.g. `new Button { preferredSize = new Dimension(60, 60)`) or revalidating the outer BoxPanel after you set the preferred sizes.

Comment: Still no luck. I ended up going back to the Java Swing libraries, which I know well. I've got it working with them.